# VSTS Organize multiple CI/CD pipelines

Tags: azure-devops

I have a solution that consist of the three following folders

iac: This folder contains all my ARM templates

func1: This folder contains my first azure function

func2: This folder contains my second azure function

I have made a CI/CD pipeline per folder which are run on every commit if something changed in a folder.

My problem is, if I change something in iac folder and func1 folder, I want to be sure that iac pipeline will be run first and then func1.

Is there a way to define that in VSTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn’t the way to define that in VSTS.

The better way is to commit and push changes of iac separately.